# ANDROID: KOTLIN, Cant read image names from drawable folder

Tags: android, kotlin

THE CODE SHOULD READ THE NAMES OF THE IMAGES IN res/drawable FOLDER, ADD THEM TO AN ARRAY AND RETURN THE ARRAY. BUT ITS RETURNING AN EMPTY ARRAY, WHAT DID I DO WRONG?

```
 private fun getImageNames(): Array<String> {
        val resources: Resources = this.resources
        val imageNames = mutableListOf<String>()

        val packageName: String = packageName
        val res = resources

        val imageResourceType = "drawable"
        val imageResources = res.assets.list(imageResourceType)

        if (imageResources != null) {
            for (imageResource in imageResources) {
                val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(imageResource, imageResourceType, packageName)

                if (resourceId != 0 && !imageResource.startsWith("np")) {
                    val imageUri = "android.resource://$packageName/$resourceId/"
                    imageNames.add(imageUri)
                }
            }
        }

        return imageNames.toTypedArray()
    }
```

The imagesNames was intended to create a listvew but Im getting an empty screen.

Comment: `WHAT DID I DO WRONG` Do not shout! Remove the caps lock.

Comment: `list()` on `Assets` is for assets, not for resources.